# I compare this 2, if i use function slideLeft(); it wont run but if i use the other 1 i run

Tags: jquery

> Running..

```
jQuery.fn.slideLeft = function(){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
```

> Error..

```
    function slideLeft(){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
```

i just wanted to know what is the difference between this two.. sorry i'm newbie in jquery. all tutorials that is watched they`re always using function example(); then this 1 with jQuery.fn its not familiar for me..

Comment: `.fn` points to the jQuery prototype

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: jQuery("#about").slideLeft(); i call it like this

Comment: Doing `jQuery.fn.slideLeft = function(){...` and then `$("#about").slideLeft();` works for me. Are you sure you have an element with that id in your page? Or that jQuery is loaded when you run that line?